# Kendo angular grid with grouping and sorting feature

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am not able to find sample(grouping and sorting feature enabled on the same grid sample) in your website(http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/). Actually I am newbie in Grid component, so anyone please provide this sample in plunker. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In their FAQ it states they have not implemented the groupable configuration yet.  Citation:  http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/faq/

According to their roadmap, their goal seems to be to implement everything missing by September.

Comment: it is possible to group and sort on the same grid as i group, sort, filter and page on all of my grids

Answer (score 0):

Bind the grid data to the '[kendoGridBinding]' property instead of using '[data]'. Set the groupable and sortable properties to true. The '[kendoGridBinding]' handles will handle the sorting, filtering, grouping and paging for you. Just set the corresponding property to true. They do have an example of this, look for the 'kendoGridBinding' property.